# problems using internal formats other than R8 for texture data

Tags: typescript, glsl, shader, webgl, webgl2

I'm using GLSL shaders with 3D texture data in WebGL2 code via TypeScript. My texture data contains single-channel samples, with different data sources using samples with different bit widths (u8, u16, u32, f32). Unfortunately, I cannot get texture formats other than `R8` to work (64 bit Chrome v104+ on Windows 10).

I see no GLSL shader/program compilation errors, and no WebGL runtime errors on the console or via return values from WebGL calls.

When I upload texture data from a `Uint8Array` as `R8` format, everything works fine. However, when I switch from `R8` to `R8UI` format (ostensibly identical data, but `usampler` in the shader vs `sampler` to return raw unsigned values rather than normalized `float`s) I get ... nothing.

All the values returned by the sampler are zero, everywhere in the 3D texture data

I checked this by modifying the shader to simply output a gray pixel wherever the sampled texture data is non-zero - no gray pixels are created.

I also tried `R16UI` and `R32F` texture formats (source data passed via e.g., `Uint8Array` or `Float32Array` ); these formats also result in textures full of zero values when the shader runs. It seems that only `R8` produces anything other than textures full of `0`.

I could perhaps try to smear 16-bit values across 2 x 8-bit values via some sort of `RG8` internal texture format, but the "correct" data types are apparently available by default in WebGL2 - I just can't seem to get them to work.

Any ideas?

Code snippets follow, with no error checking for concision:

## Main program (`R8` example)

```
// R8 - this seems to work
const data = new Uint8Array(W*H*N)
internal_format = sys.gl.R8
< ... setup data array ... >
setDataTexture(W,H,N, data, internal_format)
```

## Main program (`R8UI` example)

```
// R8UI - this doesn't seem to work, despite being ostensibly
// identical to the R8 source data
const data = new Uint8Array(W*H*N)
internal_format = sys.gl.R8UI
< ... setup data array ... >
setDataTexture(W,H,N, data, internal_format)
```

## setDataTexture()

```
setDataTexture(X: number, Y: number, Z: number, data: any, internal_format: GLenum) {
    const gl = this.gl
    const params: Record<GLenum, any> = {}
    params[gl.R8]    = ["R8",    gl.RED,         gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE]
    params[gl.R8UI]  = ["R8UI",  gl.RED_INTEGER, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE]
    params[gl.R16UI] = ["R16UI", gl.RED_INTEGER, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT]
    params[gl.R16I]  = ["R16I",  gl.RED_INTEGER, gl.SHORT]
    params[gl.R32F]  = ["R32F",  gl.RED,         gl.FLOAT]
    
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0) // bind data to texture 0

    if (this.dataTex !== null) {
        gl.deleteTexture(this.dataTex)
        this.dataTex = null
    }

    if (!params[internal_format]) {
        console.log(`Unknown internal format ${internal_format}`)
        return
    }

    const [str, fmt, typ] = params[internal_format]

    this.dataTex = gl.createTexture()
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_3D, this.dataTex)
    // UNPACK_ALIGNMENT : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51582282/error-when-creating-textures-in-webgl-with-the-rgb-format
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
    gl.texStorage3D(gl.TEXTURE_3D, 1, internal_format, X,Y,Z)
    // LINEAR filtering doesn't work for some data types, default to NEAREST for testing
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST)
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_R, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE)    
    gl.texSubImage3D(gl.TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0,0,0, X,Y,Z, fmt, typ, data)
}
```

## Fragment shader (`R8`)

```
#version 300 es

precision highp int;
precision highp float;

uniform highp sampler3D volume;

< ... etc, then loop calculating position "pos" ... >

// Assume only using red channel in texture data
float val = texture(volume, pos).r;
// ... now do something with "val"
```

## Fragment shader (`R8UI`)

```
#version 300 es

precision highp int;
precision highp float;

uniform highp usampler3D volume;

< ... etc, then loop calculating position "pos" ... >

// Assume only using red channel in texture data
uint val_ = texture(volume, pos).r;
if (val_ > 0u) {
    // write gray pixel data
}
```

Comment: Do not write the solution in the question. The solution is included in the answer.

Comment: I added my solution to the end of the question before I saw your post below that contained the same information; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your texture is incomplete. `R8UI` is a format that is not texture filterable because integer values cannot be interpolated. Therefore, both the minification filter and the magnification filter must be "nearest" value filters. You have set the minification filter

> ```js
> gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST)
> ```

however you have forgotten the magnification filter

```js
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST)
```